# Restore row CssStyle with Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

In my way I highlighting my GridView rows with this codes.

```
function onGridViewRowSelected(rowIdx) {
    var selRow = getSelectedRow(rowIdx);
    if (curSelRow != null) {
        curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    } if (null != selRow) {
        curSelRow = selRow;
        curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = '#ababab';
    }
    clearTimeout(rowHighLightTimeOut);
}
```

when i define AlternateRowCssStyle in my GridView codes working, but clearing all defined alternate CssStyle in the GridView when onmouseover. For prevent this, i thing need to catch current cell style and load it again when onmouse out? 
How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. sorry for mistake. i edited codes. This codes working but need to restore my alternate row css to prevent applying "transparent" background for all my rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function onGridViewRowSelected(rowIdx) {
    var selRow = getSelectedRow(rowIdx);
    if (curSelRow != null) {
        curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = curRowSty;
    } if (null != selRow) {
        curSelRow = selRow;
        curRowSty = curSelRow.style.backgroundColor;
        curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = '#ababab';
    }
    clearTimeout(rowHighLightTimeOut);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to Use **[style](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp)**

```
curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for prompt response.
sorry for mistake. i edited codes. 
This codes working but need to restore my alternate row css to prevent applying "transparent" background for all my rows.

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer.